# Is it possible to use jsp variable value to initialize JQUERY variable?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have some questions which are as follows:

1. How can I use the JSP variable/array in JQUERY code? Here what ever the JQUERY code we have is stored in separate .js file and that file is included in the JSP file.
2. Actually I want to initialize the JQUERY array with the JSP variable.
   So please guide me to achieve this task.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Plain Old JSP

```
<script>
  var someText = "<%= myBean.getText() %>";
</script>
```

Using EL (Expression Language)

```
<script>
  var someText = "${myBean.text}";
</script>
```

Using Struts

```
<script>
  var someText = '<bean:write name="myBean" property="text" />';
</script>
```

Using JSTL

```
<script>
  var someText = '<c:out value="${myBean.text}" />';
</script>
```

In essence, it's possible to populate Javascript objects from JSP. Don't forget that scriptlets and tags are just rendered back as HTML/XHTML, so JS cannot talk to tags and vice-versa.

Comment: The 2nd example doesn't use JSTL at all. It's called EL (Expression Language).

Comment: But EL was part of JSTL - http://www.jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/first/jsr052 (Appendix A) :)

Comment: As this answer floats to the top I'll repeat my comment from another answer, especially for the "Plain Old JSP" solution: Note the XSS implications: String theVar = "hello'; alert(\"XSS\"); //"

Comment: True Olaf...hence it's better to use JSTL `<fmt />` for such implications and move away from "Plain Old JSP".

Comment: Erm, the `fmt` taglib doesn't take care about XSS. The `c:out` and `fn:escapeXml` does.

Comment: @BalusC, true....I used the `fn:replace` to solve XSS, I was thinking struts when I wrote this. In struts you can handle XSS by allowing `filter="true"` on `bean:write`

Comment: Ahh, JSP injection! What if the text is: `"; alert('Hi Jim!'); var foo = "`?

Comment: @Konrad Garus then the OP didn't introduce proper validation on his data! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Java/JSP runs in webserver at the server machine and produces HTML/CSS/JS code. Server machine sends HTML/CSS/JS code to client machine. HTML/CSS/JS runs in webbrowser at client machine. Rightclick page and view source, you don't see any Java/JSP code.

JSP is a view technology which provides a template to write HTML/CSS/JS in and the ability to interact with backend Java data using taglibs/EL to control page flow and access data.

Whenever you want to let JavaScript access Java/JSP variables, all you need to do is to just write a Java variable **as if** it is a JavaScript variable.

```
<script>var foo = '${bean.foo}';</script>
```

Is an excellent example. Note that those quotes are required for JavaScript itself, not for JSP/EL. Imagine that `${bean.foo}` returns `bar`, then the generated HTML/CSS/JS page which arrived at the client side would end up looking like:

```
<script>var foo = 'bar';</script>
```

Whenever you want to let Java/JSP access JavaScript variables, all you need to do is to let JavaScript fire a (XML)HTTP request. More background info and examples can be found in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You'd have to set it into the page somewhere.

```
<script>
   var fromJsp = '${theVar}';
</script>
```

Note that this could get tricky for complex objects. Maybe JSON serialization can be your friend here.

Also note that this is one-way only. It is impossible to set the value of JSP variables from JavaScript (since the JavaScript runs client-side after the JSP has finished its work).

Comment: Note the XSS implications: String theVar = "hello'; alert(\"XSS\"); //"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

`<input type="hidden" id="var1" value="<%=jspVar%>" />`


and then use var1 in jQuery.

Comment: Assuming that the variable is a string and that it doesn't contain a " character.