# setting a variable in JSP and using it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I have a route object. It contains arrayList of options. I want to know the size of options and store it in some variable. (This thing needs to be done in JSP). I then want to access this variable in jquery. How to do it?

JSP code :

```
<%!int loopSize = routes.get(0).getOptions().size(); %>
  <c:forEach var="route" items="${routes}" varStatus="loopCounter">
    <c:forEach var="option" items="${route.options}" 
               varStatus="loopCounter2">
    <---more code -->
    </c:forEach> 
  </c:forEach>
```

But it is saying routes undefined. I am using struts2 and action class. Routes is coming from the action class

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried so far so that we can help you better.

Comment: Okay Sir.. I will edit the question to include code

Comment: see this if it helps!     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780996/how-can-we-get-javascript-array-by-jsp-scriptlet

Comment: are you setting `routes` object in session or request scope?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use jsp variable value to initialize JQUERY variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431084/is-it-possible-to-use-jsp-variable-value-to-initialize-jquery-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution may be to store the length of array in hidden field and access it in jquery.

```
<input type="hidden" id="loopSize" name= "loopSize" value= "${fn:length(routes[0].options)}"/>
```

And using the id you can accesss the value in jquery

Comment: This really isn't the best answer.  Yes it will work, but why (1) assign a variable to hidden input so that you can (2) retrieve the value of the hidden input via JavaScript and (3) assign it to a JavaScript variable when you could simply assign it to the variable.  See my answer below as well as this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431084/is-it-possible-to-use-jsp-variable-value-to-initialize-jquery-variable) and this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287114/how-to-set-the-jstl-variable-value-in-javascript).